# Question related with Opportunities and accounts

Tags: opportunity, account, ownership, record-owner

I have been working with Salesforce for not more than 2 years, I still finding things that amaze me... but not is something that I've been struggling for a few hours now.

Every new opportunity has always need to have the same account owner or I am missing some automation in between? Every opportunity I create is changed to the Account owner if is different, reading Salesforce Docs seems that it always has been like that, or all the opportunities can have different owners even with the same Account?

If the answer is that I'm missing some automation, where can I found it? (I'm checking process builder already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given Account owner Alice and Opportunity owner Bob, Bob may have an Opportunity on Alice's Account. By default, Salesforce doesn't automatically change the Opportunity Owner to match the Account, nor does it validate that that this rule is enforced. It's very common in many organizations for Sales Associates to share an Account.

Your organization may have an Apex Trigger, Process Builder, or Record-Launched Flow that is automatically enforcing ownership changes. You can generally use the Developer Console (⚙ > Developer Console) to read the logs as a record is modified to try and figure out exactly which configuration changed the ownership.

Comment: Hey, thank you I wasn't very intuitive but I was able to track the Apex Trigger from here... Glad to be part of this community